# cocos2d js Masking image error in scene

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I have problem masking image in cocos2d-js. Using this code i have successfully masked image and added this to Scene but after switching back to previous scene where i have written this code in previous scene, error comes.

```
// Create a mask
var maskSprite = new cc.Sprite(spriteFrameCache.getSpriteFrame("mask.png"));
// maskSprite.setBlendFunc(cc.ONE, cc.ZERO);
maskSprite.setPosition(maskSprite.width / 2, maskSprite.height / 2);

var puzzleImage = new cc.Sprite(spriteFrameCache.getSpriteFrame("puzzle.png"));

puzzleImage.setBlendFunc(cc.DST_ALPHA, cc.ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);


puzzleImage.setPosition(maskSprite.width / 2, maskSprite.height / 2);

var cs = maskSprite.getBoundingBox();
var rendererTexture = new cc.RenderTexture(cs.width, cs.height);

rendererTexture.beginWithClear(0, 0, 0, 0);
// rendererTexture.begin();

maskSprite.visit();
puzzleImage.visit();

rendererTexture.end();

var rtSprite = new cc.Sprite();
rtSprite.initWithTexture(rendererTexture.getSprite().getTexture());
rtSprite.getTexture().setAntiAliasTexParameters();
rtSprite.flippedY = true;

rtSprite.setPosition(500,450);
this.addChild( rtSprite,20);
```

I am getting correct result once i added this in scene but switching scene back and forth its creating bug.

Something Like - RendererWebGL.js:314 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

To reproduce this problem add this code to your main scene.
Now change your scene to any other scene and again come back to previous scene.

Please help me...